# how to redirect any URI to case insensitive URI in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to redirect any sensitive URI to case-insensitive in nginx server.
For Ex. www.doamin.com/foobar or www.doamin.com/FooBar or
www.doamin.com/FOOBAR or www.doamin.com/fooBAR should be redirected to www.doamin.com/foobar i.e., whatever the URI user enter, it should be redirect to its lower-case.

Is there anyone faced this requirement, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~* ^/foobar {
    rewrite (?i)^/foobar /foobar break;
}
```

and if foobar is a path,you can try this

```
location ~* ^/foobar {
    rewrite (?i)^/foobar(.*) /foobar$1 break;
}
```

Comment: What can be the solution if I want to convert all the strings in the url to case-insensitive nomatter whatever is the URI.

My client is not allowing me to install perl or leo library to achieve this in nginx, can you provide some solution for this?

Comment: convert all the strings, I has not try it,you can try ngx_http_lower_upper_case module, git address is https://github.com/replay/ngx_http_lower_upper_case